# IOS/Android - Best approach for animated site

Tags: jquery, ios, flash, html, canvas

I have been tasked with building a HTML5 based App which will contain various animated children's games.  The app needs to work in both Android and IOS environments.

My obvious choice would be to build a Flash site as I have Flash good animation and Action-script experience, but there are the obvious IOS/Flash player issues.

Just wonder if anyone has any experience with cross device animation and could offer any advice on pros and cons of the following approaches -

- Flash App - (compiled to IOS friendly code using cs5.5)
- Code using Jquery animation
- Use new HTML Canvas tool.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: If you are making an app, and not a mobile website, what reason would you not use flash? It compiles to iOS and android.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer with previous bad experience, I dont recommend phone gap at all. There are some VERY nice "layer" libraries for web development that allows the site to interact with a touch screen via "Middle Man" translation libraries. I'd look into those and make it a mobile website instead of a mobile app. If you're required to push for an app, you could always make a NATIVE (non-phonegapped) iOS/Android application that basically contains a website and some form of navigation to move throughout the games hosted on your site.

Please, for the sake of your users, avoid tools like phonegap.

PS - The only downside to this approach is Apple is against making a mobile app that is just a better formatted web application, although through the use of these libraries, I think it'd pass review.